# adb command to connect phone to known bluetooth device(my headphones. using it's name or MAC e.g)?

Tags: adb, bluetooth, headphones

I'm going to automate the reconnection of the headphones between my computer and phone based on events on the phone and computer.
how can i tell my phone (using adb) to connect to the known headphones ?
now i can connect/disconnect it to my pc. and on phone i can on/off bluetooth and get list of bonded devices..

i know its mac if needed..
now i can [dis]connect my phones from pc using:

> `bluetoothctl connect [MAC]` and `bluetoothctl disconnect [MAC]`

> and line in bash script `if [[ $(bluetoothctl info [MAC] | grep "Connected: no") == "" ]];` to get state.

i'm using `adb shell settings put global bluetooth_disabled_profiles 1` to turn phone bt on and "0" at the end to turn off(to disconnect from headphones e.g.).  using the

> `adb shell "dumpsys bluetooth_manager | sed -n '/Bonded devices:/,/^$/p'"`

command i'm getting bt devices list with mac, supported bt profiles and some other info that i cant identify. will it help me to write a command to connect headphones to phone?..